# Trouble with a do while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to return a *random* number that has to be between two numbers, the way I'm doing this is setting up a loop to check that it is between those numbers, if not , re-roll.

The problem I'm having is that it will never break out of my loop and I can't work it out, is it because the variable doesn't get passed out of the loop to be retested?

If so, is it some kind of return or break I need to do?

Code:

```
int randDamRange = 0
byte DamRange = attack.getM_damageRange(); //In this case 75

//Create a random number from within the attack damage range
do
{
    Random randbetween = new Random();

    randDamRange = randbetween.nextInt(DamRange);
    randDamRange = 75; //Test Should breakout of loop           
}   
while ((randDamRange < DamMin) || (randDamRange < DamMax));
```

Comment: In addition to the answers to your actual question, note that creating a new Random instance every time you need a random number does not get the benefit of Random's algorithm. It is better to use one Random for a whole series of numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your loop condition:

```
while ((randDamRange < 50) || (randDamRange < 115));
```

Now think about `randDamRange` being 75. Why would you *not* expect it to keep going? 75 is less than 115.

Note that as 50 is less than 115, your loop condition is exactly equivalent to:

```
while (randDamRange < 115);
```

I *suspect* you meant:

```
while (randDamRange < 50 || randDamRange > 115)
```

but if so, it would be *much* simpler to get a random number in the range `[0, 65]` and add 50... There's no need to loop at all. (It's not clear how `getM_damageRange()` comes into things.)

Comment: Of course, it's been a long day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution to get a random number between 50 and 115 would be to get a random number between 0 and 65 and add 50:

```
Random randbetween = new Random();
randDamRange = randbetween.nextInt(65);
randDamRange += 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the easiest way to do this is:

```
int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 76)
```

The general way is:

```
int randomNumber = minimalValue + (int)(Math.random() * ((maximalValue - minimalValue) + 1))
```